# How to call a specific library file inside the div

Tags: 8

I have declared the external library and calling this library for a particular page using preprocess html.

The Library file has been called for the particular page and showing the script content at the bottom of the page.

Now I want to wrap the script content between the div

How do I wrap the script content between the Div using preprocess html or Any Other ways to wrap the script ?

Answer (score 2):

Attaching a library via the `#attached` tag will add it to the header (or bottom of the page if that's the settings). It does not get added into the "content" area. So, wrapping it in a `<div>` is not applicable.

If you are using JS to generate some content that needs to be placed on the page, then it needs to be written to find some selector and insert the content.  E.g.

```
jQuery('#my-dynamic-content').html("My new div content");
```

Then just add the `<div id="my-dynamic-content"></div>` to your template/content as needed.